# How to use environmental variables in a static Netlify page

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, netlify, netlify-cms

So i have a static Webpage which uses some API. There's **app.js** file that has API key in it stored in an object property.I need to hide it using *Netlify* dev. How do I do that? How do I use *Netlify* dev tools in native js? I most probably need node js installed as well but this topic is not entirely clear to me... Could someone make a step by step tutorial for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a static site, it won't be able to directly access the hidden netlify env variables.
If you are hosting the `app.js` file along with your static site then it will be easy for someone to browse to it and see the API key you are trying to hide.

One solution though is to define a [Netlify Function](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/build-with-javascript/#format) that does the API call, and then the JS in your static site can call that function.
Your Netlify Function will be effectively a backend for your app, and can access the ENV variables you set in the Netlify UI, via `process.env`.

See this [tutorial](https://dev.to/fabiorosado/hide-your-api-keys-with-netlify-functions-93m) for a step-by-step guide.

---

Update re the new gatsby-build information in comments.

You can put variables in a git-ignored `.env` file, which means they will not end up on git, but will still get pulled in and included in the gatsby production code, which will be visible to the client, so isn't recommended for API access keys. Ideally you should connect via a backend to secure those keys, as in the above original answer.

However, instead of using a .env file, if you are using the Netlify Dev CLI then this will automatically pull down any env vars you have set in the online Netlify settings, and allow you to use those in your local environment.

From the [cli docs](https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#netlify-dev):

> Netlify Dev brings the functionality of your Netlify production environment directly to your local machine. This includes custom headers/redirects and **environment variables**.

Comment: hi Luke, in my case, I need to use the Environmental variables in the front-end(Gatsby.js) , I am able to use them in gatsby-browser.js, but not able to do the same in a js file that I created myself. Could you help please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611042/netlify-gasby-how-to-use-environmental-or-os-variables-in-self-created-javascr?noredirect=1#comment112484357_63611042

Comment: Have you checked the compiled gatsby output? There is a chance that Gatsby is actually just pulling in your local environment variables into the sourcecode, and then that is being deployed, rather than it actually using netlify's env vars at run time.

Comment: I thought the ```.env``` and ```.env.development``` are used for both Gatsby and Netlify cms. Where are the Netlify's env vars? I know there are settings on Netlify's settings, but that's for production. For local development, how are you going to use the Netlify's env vars?

Comment: See updated answer and https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#netlify-dev